# Compute number of elements in a cycle

Tags: number-theory

Given numbers from **1 to N** and a number **K** can we find the number of cycles beginning at number **1**. **K** is the distance to the next number. Elements **1 to N** are arranged in a circular order.(**N and 1** are adjacent).

For eg : N = 7 and K = 2
then, 1 --> 3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 2 --> 4 --> 6 --> 1 and the cycle terminates.
Number of elements covered is 7.

Comment: Are $1\to 2\to 3\to 4\to 5\to 6\to 7\to 1$ and $1\to 7\to 6\to 5\to 4\to 3\to 2\to 1$ considered equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one such cycle, determined by the value of $K$. The title and your example suggest that what you mean to ask about is the length of the cycle.

For that question here's a hint. Work out all the examples for $N=6$ and think about the greatest common divisor of $N$ and $K$.

(You can make nice pictures of stars with chords of a circle.)

Comment: Thanks it really helped :)